# Cassandra 1.2: Is CQL preferred over Thrift Based Clients

Tags: cassandra, pycassa

I'm finally getting the hang of Cassandra, part of the issue was learning / respecting the differences between Thrift and CQL3.

Many of the tutorials I am finding online are for CQL3.  My question:  Is CQL3 truly the preferred method, and is Thrift being discouraged?  Reason I ask is I spent a couple of days trying to get what I needed through Pycassa which does not support Cassandra 1.2 and that is based on the Thrift model.

Comment: In case you're not aware of it, this driver is your best option for working with CQL3 through python: https://github.com/datastax/python-driver.  (I'm the author of it, and the maintainer of pycassa.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Is CQL3 truly the preferred method, and is Thrift being discouraged?*

Short answer is **yes**.

Longer answer is:

CQL3 should be preferred for many reasons:

1. platform-agnostic language: CQL3 looks like SQL and is easier to handle that pure Thrift API code.
2. Higher level of abstraction: for end-users, it's easier to deal with CQL3 to query data rather than juggling with low-level Thrift API, although some good higher abstraction frameworks exist (Hector for Java, Pycassa for Python ...=
3. Easier to administer for operational teams: when creating a new table or adding new **referential** data, it is easier to write CQL3 scripts that ops teams can understand, check and execute rather than cryptic cassandra-cli scripts (set cf[rowKey][columnName] = ...). I'm migrating all our cassandra-cli scripts to CQL3 because it's a pain in the ass to maintain them
4. Last but not least, CQL3 make life easier for third-party framework developers. I've developed **[Achilles](https://github.com/doanduyhai/Achilles/wiki)**, an open-source persistence manager for Cassandra. The Thrift version was painfull to implement, the CQL3 version was a piece of cake escpecially because it uses the Java Driver from Datastax

That being said, CQL3 is no bed of roses either. Before **leveraging the full power of the query language, you need to understand how Cassandra storage engine works**. The language gives you the illusion that everything is easy and will work as SQL but the plain truth is no. There are some important semantics differences, especially when using the **WHERE** clause.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, CQL is the preferred API.  It is much easier to use and not all operations are supported through the Thrift API.

You can use cassandra-dbapi2 for CQL3 in Python: https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-dbapi2/.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes

However given how new it is compared to thrift based clients it is safe to assume there is vastly more thrift clients in production.

Given Datastax now produce their own Java driver that supports exclusively CQL3 it is probably a good idea to follow suite: https://github.com/datastax/java-driver